# Асинхронные потоки PHP

Tags: php, потоки-данных

Можно ли сделать как-нибудь асинхронный поток на PHP, т.е. чтобы что-то выполнялось и одновременно обрабатывались запросы к серверу и могли быть запущены другие асинхронные потоки?

К примеру: пользователь присылает материал, который должен поддаться доооооолгой обработке, и сервер обрабатывает эти материалы, а также одновременно другие запросы.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вам надо по другому сделать. Сначала ваш скрипт сложит в определенной место данную задачу и отдаст ответ, что задача в процессе. Далее по мере обращения к задаче он проверяет готовность е выполнения и отдает ответ в случае успешности. Другой скрипт (скрытый от пользователей) берет задачи и начинает выполнять-он уж может длиться оч. долго (например его крон запускает) и к тому же может быть написан не на пхп (что лучше). Пусть контентом управляет пхп, а сверхзадачи делает си код.

Answer (score 0):

На php нет, асинхронность - это технология ajax =) Но это не страшно, даже если ты его не знаешь, сейчас готовых примеров реализации полно. В частности ajax-формы как раз для обработки такого плана.

Comment: C ajax я знаком. Без него сейчас никуда. Использую вместе с jQuery. Программировал на ASP.NET, просто перехожу на php - он бесплатный.
А разве ajax подойдёт для моих целей? Может вы меня не так поняли?

Если по-потробней пример:
Мне присылают на сервер некоторое зашифрованное сообщение, а я должен его расшифровать подбирая ключ. Это может длиться ооооооочень долго(дни, недели). На странице пользователь отправляет это сообщение и ему ответ: "Ваше сообщение будет обработано. Ждите..." и сервер продолжает обработку запросов, в то время как происходит подбор ключа.

Comment: Как это реализовать? На ASP сама платформа .NET предоставляет крутой класс BackgroundWorker и ещё библиотека System.Threading, которые работают с потоками.

Comment: да, не так поняла=/
Вообще, php изначально не имеет поддержки асинхронности, но псевдо-асинхронность некоторым извращенным методом можно создать.
http://nickyaitsky.com/ - вот здесь, в статье Nick Yaitsky "Asynchronous PHP calls" описан подобный пример.
Возможно, он вам подойдет, хотя, если честно, asp была бы и правда лучше.

Comment: конечно лучше, но просто php бесплатный, а это + (большущий +)

Answer (score 0):

Костыль - юзер заполняет форму, шлет ее на сервер, скрипт делает пост-запрос на себя с каким-то параметром (exec=yes&secrect_code=12345), ждет "ОК" из сокета, обрывает соединение и пишет юзеру "Ждите".

Не-совсем-костыль: `exec("php /path/to/script.php");`, но там еще что-то надо сделать, чтоб не ждать ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Из коробки в PHP это не возможно реализовать. Однако существуют проект под названием [phpDaemon](http://phpdaemon.net/), который позволяет реализовывать асинхронную обработку данных.

Answer (score 0):

В таком раскладе с применением возможно только костыльное решение. Настоящего BackgroundWorker'а не дождётесь. Это в принципе невозможно, так как процесс PHP не висит всё время, как висит виртуальная машина .NET или Java, поэтому никакие потоки не будут жить дольше, чем генерируется страница.

Таким образом, ваш вариант - всякие хитрые манипуляции с exec или cron, incron и т.п.