# Многопоточность в PHP (или ее эмуляция)

Tags: сокеты, многопоточность, php

Есть набор задач, которые нужно распараллелить:

> Поисковый запрос пользователя
>   передается нескольким поисковым
>   системам, результаты объединяются и
>   возвращаются пользователю. Идея в том,
>   чтобы запросы к сайтам были не
>   последовательными (критично время
>   ожидания), а параллельными.

Зацепила идея [выставления задачи отдельному скрипту или демону..., чтобы потом ajax'ом проверять завершение выполнения задачи](http://ru-php.livejournal.com/1489056.html?thread=22153888#t22153888). Год назад @org, отвечая на вопрос о асинхронных потоках, [описывал логику работы, которая, на мой взгляд может быть здесь полезна](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/22146/%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-php):

1. Скрипт A складывает в определенное место задачу и отдаёт ответ, что задача в процессе.
2. Скрипт Б (скрытый от пользователей) берет активные задачи и начинает выполнять.
3. Скрипт А проверяет статус задачи (в процессе / выполнена / не выполнена) и отдает ответ в случае успешности.

Пункты 1 и 3 - понятны. А вот мысль про отдельный скрипт (2) или даже отдельные скрипты - не совсем. В общем, буду рад наводкам на возможные решения.

---

UPD. Ковыряю и модифицирую код, который приводится на странице [Разработка многозадачных приложений на PHP v5](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/os-php-multitask/). Попробовал добавить два сайта. В чем затык?

```
<?php
  $timeout               = 10; 
  $result                = array(); 
  $sockets               = array(); 
  $convenient_read_block = 8192;
  $urls                  = array('ya.ru', 'google.com');
  $id                    = 0;

  foreach($urls as $url) {
    $s = stream_socket_client($url . ":80", $errno, $errstr, $timeout,
            STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT); 
    if ($s) { 
      $sockets[$id++] = $s; 
      fwrite($s, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: " . $url . "\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n");
    } else {
      echo "Stream " . $id . " failed to open correctly.";
    } 
  } 

  while (count($sockets)) { 
    $read = $sockets; 
    stream_select($read, $w = null, $e = null, $timeout); 
    if (count($read)) {
      foreach ($read as $r) { 
        $id   = array_search($r, $sockets); 
        $data = fread($r, $convenient_read_block); 
        if (strlen($data) == 0) { 
          fclose($r); 
          unset($sockets[$id]); 
        } else { 
          $result[$id] .= $data; 
        } 
      } 
    } else { 
      echo "Time-out!\n";
      break;
    } 
  }
?>
```

Comment: Подавляющее большинство тех кто пишет на php, являются веб-разработчиками.

Подавляющее большинство веб-разработчиков знают в той или иной степени JavaScript.

Внимание, вопрос: почему не node.js?

Comment: @neoascetic, это моя первая мысль и я над ней думаю. Хочется однако узнать и об альтернативах.

Comment: @neoascetic - знать "в той или иной степени", к сожалению - недостаточно :)

Вообще не вижу проблемы реализации пункта Б на php, CRON же.

Comment: Жаль, что нет кнопки "мне не нравится этот комментарий".

Comment: @DenisKhvorostin теперь есть такая кнопка, флажок на ней )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мысли вслух: нечто навроде MapReduce.
Пусть JS на стороне пользователя делает асинхронный запрос к разным частям сервер-сайда, которые, очевидно, будут выполняться параллельно:

```
/foo/
/bar/
/baz/
```

И потом же он (клиент-сайд) сам собирает то, что получил. Таким образом, распараллеливание задачи мы возлагаем на веб-сервер, который будет форкать (или что там он делает) обработчики, и на клиент-сайд

Comment: Ага. Эта часть квеста мне понятна. Вопрос в том, что должно быть на сервер-сайде в данном описании.

Comment: При условии, что скорость доступа к каждому отдельному сервису удовлетворительная - то хоть PHP. Каждый скрипт будет работать параллельно и выдавать результат как только его получит (и обработает).

Проблема только, если клиенту необходимо отобразить результат, только когда получит ответы **из всех** источников (для сортировки или еще чего). MapReduce же! :D

Comment: Node.js - не вариант: ограничение хостинга ("К сожалению, такой возможности не имеется. В настоящее время, использование данного скрипта возможно только на тарифах VDS без администрирования")

Comment: Промахнулись, куда коммент отправить? Потому как в этом ответе предполагается JS использовать на клиенте, на сервере какие угодно обработчики, хоть brainfuck :) Главное, чтобы общались на одном языке (JSON, разумеется)

Answer (score 0):

cURL'ом делайте параллельные запросы.
См. пример и комменты к [curl_mutli_init](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php)

Answer (score 0):

Если всё серьёзно, можно попробовать Job-сервер поставить, например [Gearman](http://gearman.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Для многопоточности можно использовать это https://github.com/stas29a/php_threads 
Там реализован весь функционал необходимый для полноценного решения задачи многопоточности. 
Ну а всякие нюансы можете сами допилить под свои требования.